# If bool is a macro for int, why is it a different size?

Tags: c, memory, int, boolean

I was hoping somebody could explain why

```
#include <stdbool.h>

printf("size of bool %d\n", sizeof(bool));
printf("size of int %d\n", sizeof(int));
```

outputs to

```
size of bool 1
size of int 4
```

I've looked at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html which seems to indicate that bool is essentially a macro for _Bool which, when set to true or false, is really just a macro for an integer constant.  If it is an integer, why is it not the same size?

I'm asking because it took us far too long to debug a program for which we did not allocate enough memory.

Comment: Just curious — if a `bool` is *smaller* than you expected, how did you not allocate enough memory?

Comment: @detly Well, to be honest we aren't sure.  We had an array of `bool` that always resulted in a segmentation fault until we multiplied the `malloc(x*sizeof(bool))` by `malloc(4*x*sizeof(bool))`  It could have been something completely different, but that solved the problem and led me to this question.

Comment: Were you declaring a `bool*`? We don't have much to go on without the code, though that would probably be a separate question (and it sounds like you might have been allocating for `bool` but writing larger objects to the allocated storage.

Comment: @birrytree we were declaring a bool***.  But you are definitely right, it would be a separate question.  Hopefully with these awesome answers I'll be able to figure out what the real problem is.

Comment: You were declaring triple pointers - at what level were you allocating `x*sizeof(bool)`? For the first two levels, which are pointers-to-pointers, you would have to allocate `sizeof(bool*)` because `sizeof(bool*)` is likely not equal to `sizeof(bool)`.

Comment: @birrtree  That is very interesting.  We were allocationg `x*sizeof(bool)` for every level.  But now that you mention it, (and I sit and think about it) we would need to allocate memory for the pointer and not the actual `bool` for all levels except the last.  Wow!  As I mentioned in your answer, this has been very educational and helpful!

Comment: Yep, for the first two levels, since they will be pointers to pointers, you have to allocate space to store pointers, so use something like `x*sizeof(bool*)` instead of `x*sizeof(bool)`. This way you won't have to do something like `4*x*sizeof(bool)`, because that would only help you on systems where pointers are 4-bytes wide (32-bit programs). In a 64-bit program, you'd run into memory crashes again. `sizeof(bool*)` will work correctly on either 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `_Bool` type in C99 (`typedef`'ed to `bool` in `stdbool.h`) doesn't have a standard defined size, but according to section 6.2.5 of the C99 Standard:

```
2 An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.
```

In C, the smallest addressable object (aside from bitfields) is the `char`, which is at least 8-bits wide, and `sizeof(char)` is always `1`.

`_Bool` and `bool` therefore have a `sizeof` of at least `1`, and in most implementations that I've seen, `sizeof(bool)` / `sizeof(_Bool)` is `1`.

If you take a look at GCC's `stdbool.h`, you'll get this:

```
 #define bool    _Bool
 #if __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L && __GNUC__ < 3
 typedef int _Bool;
 #endif

 #define false   0
 #define true    1
```

So if using an older version of GCC and an old version of the C standard when compiling, you will use `int` as a `_Bool` type.

Of course, as an interesting thing, check this out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(_Bool));
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(true));
   printf("%zu\n", sizeof(false));

}
```

Output:

```
λ > ./a.out 
1
4
4
```

GCC 4.2.4, Clang 3.0, and GCC 4.7.0 all output the same. As trinithis points out, `sizeof(true)` and `sizeof(false)` produce larger sizes because they are taking the size of an int literal, which is at least `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm still beginning with C and I've learned much more from your reply than just the answer to the question.

Comment: The sizeof makes sense because they are #defines for int literals. Sizeof an int literal is sizeof int. true and false are int literals in this case.

Comment: @trinithis - yeah, just wanted to draw attention to the different `sizeof`s you'd get if you tried it against the type vs. the other macros provided by the header.

Comment: Just as a nitpick, the correct `printf` format for `size_t` is `z`, here `%zu` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @JensGustedt - edited to reflect the correct modifier.

Answer (score 3):

C99 standard introduced the `_Bool` type. `_Bool` is  guaranteed to be big enough to hold integer constants 0 or 1  , this does  not neccessarily mean it is an int. The actual size is compiler dependent.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure it is dependant on your compiler, perhaps yours is using byte instead of int for bool? Either way you shouldn't have memory allocation problems if you use sizeof() to know how much memory to allocate, for example, if you want to allocate 10 bools worth of memory, don't allocate 10 * 4, do 10 * sizeof(bool) so you can't go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is an integer, but not an `int`. `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, etc., are all integers. `char` is guaranteed to have a size of 1. The rest are at least as large as char (and it's hard to imagine how you'd make the I/O system work correctly if `int` wasn't larger than char). There's also a required order from `char` to `long long` (same order I listed them above) where each type must have at least as much range as its predecessors.

Other than that, however, you're not guaranteed much about sizes of integer types. Specifically, `char` is the only one of the "base" types that has a guaranteed size (though there are types like `int8_t` and `int32_t` that have guaranteed sizes).

Answer (score 1):

As I know from porting code from Windows to Unix you can never be sure about the size of a datatype. It depends on the operating system and sometimes even on the compiler you use.

The specifications of stdbool.h only say that TRUE and FALSE are mapped to an integer (1 and 0). This does't mean that the datatype bool is of type int. From my experience bool is of the smallest datatype available (i.e char or byte):

```
bool flag = TRUE; -> byte flag = 0x01;
```

In eclipse CDT and Visual Studio you can follow the macro definitions in order to see what really lies behind your datatypes.

So I would suggest you always ask your compiler about the memory space needed in order to allocate enough memory (This is also what I saw in a lot of libraries):

```
malloc(4*sizeof(bool));
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know you could follow macro definitions in eclipse.  It's always nice to learn much more than just the answer to the original question!

Answer (score 0):

The _Bool is native to the compiler, is defined in C99 and may be activated like `gcc -std=c99`; stdbool.h #define bool to be _Bool, and true and false to simply int literals that pretty well fit into that _Bool.