# Why was the boolean data type not implemented in C

Tags: c, boolean

One of my friends asked a question, why is there no `Boolean` data type in the C programming language. I did a bit of searching and reading. I got few questions and answers in stack overflow saying that,

1. All data types should be addressable, and a bit cannot be addressed.
2. The basic data structure at the hardware level of mainstream CPUs is a byte. Operating on bits in these CPUs require additional processing.

We can use a bool in this manner

```
#define bool int
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

or use `typedef`s.

But my question is this: why wasn't it implemented as a data type in C, even after  so many years. doesn't it make sense to implement a one byte data type to store a boolean value rather than using `int` or `short` explicitly.

Comment: It's there. Look up `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type/1608350#1608350

Comment: i looked inside `<stdbool.h>` but that uses integer as a return type. why integer, wont 4 bytes be redundant (considering sizeof(int) = 4), if we can do that using just 1 byte

Comment: @ralph - `sizeof(bool)` depends on the implementation, but if you're in C99 mode, `sizeof(bool)` is typically equal to `1`. I answered a similar question long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10630231/297696. Older implementations may keep `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(int)` (or whatever) for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Just as a note, how is a boolean type really useful? Boolean variables (or functions returning them) often have quite descriptive names: `isValid`, `hasAttribute`, `needsFree`, ... And (as the others said, one bit isn't addressable in C) there wouldn't be any performance gain justifying such thing. C was designed very minimal (today less so, but still).

Comment: @mafso example - `bool b = (x & 0x8000);`  . If `bool` is an alias for `char` then this will set it to `false` even if the intended bit is set. This problem is more insidious for a function that takes bool as parameter, or returns bool.

Comment: @ralph: `<stdbool.h>` doesn't declare any functions; what "return type" are you referring to? Neither the `<stdbool.h>` on my system nor the description in the C standard refers to `int`. All it does is define a few macros. `_Bool` is the built-in Boolean type (the name was chosen to avoid conflicting with existing code).

Comment: You're conflating a logical Boolean type (which has values `false` and `true`) with a *bit* type. The built-in type `_Bool` can hold a *logical* true or false value, but an object of type `_Bool` occupies at least one byte.

Comment: @KeithThompson,
i was confused about the return type being integer in `stdbool.h`. now its clarified that newer version of gcc has _Bool of size 1 byte.

Comment: @ralph: What "return type" are you referring to? Functions have return types. `<stdbool.h>` declares no functions. The same C standard that introduced `<stdbool.h>` also introduced the built-in type `_Bool`; the macro `bool` in `<stdbool.h>` has *always* expanded to `_Bool`. (Incidentally, `_Bool` is an integer type. Don't confuse `int`, which is one specific integer type, with "integer", which describes a collection of types including `_Bool`, `char`, `int`, and a number of others.

Comment: @KeithThompson: oook. i was so confused when i saw in `http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdbool.h.html` that _Bool variables true/flase expand to integer constant 1/0. i thought then it should be of 4 bytes. now i understand.. :)

Comment: `false` and `true` are macros, not variables. They do expand to the constants `0` and `1`, respectively, and those constants are of type `int` (as I could have explained before if you hadn't talked about "return types"). But expressions of type `int` can be implicitly *converted* to `_Bool`, so the fact that `false` and `true` expand to expressions of type `int` is not a problem. Similarly, character constants and enumeration constants are also of type `int`. (An aside: C++ has different rules.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: now i understood everything clearly. thanx..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not true any more. The built-in boolean type, aka `_Bool` is available since [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). If you include [`stdbool.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#stdbool.h), its alias `bool` is also there for you.

---

`_Bool` is a true native type, not an alias of `int`. As for its size, the standard only specifies it's large enough to store `0` and `1`. But in practice, most compilers do make its size `1`:

For example, this [code snippet on ideone](http://ideone.com/vdOV46) outputs `1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(void) {
    bool b = true;
    printf("size of b: %zu\n", sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i got this. but again the thing that comes in my mind is why will it return integer. the data type _Bool could have had its own native type which would take up only 1 Byte.

Comment: thanx.. i got it now..  :)

Comment: because the smallest addressable memory element size is 1 byte, so they can't make it 1 bit or less than 1 byte, unless its address aren't gonna be taken

Answer (score 5):

C99 added support for boolean type `_Bool`, is not simply a typedef and does not have to be the same size as *int*, from the draft C99 standard section `6.2.5` *Types*:

> An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1.

We have convenience  macros through the `stdbool.h` header. we can see this from going to the draft C99 standard section `7.16` *Boolean type and values*  whcih says:

> The header  defines four macros.
>
> The macro
>
> > bool
>
> expands to _Bool.
>
> The remaining three macros are suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. They
>   are
>
> > true
>
> which expands to the integer constant 1,
>
> > false
>
> which expands to the integer constant 0, and
>
> > __bool_true_false_are_defined
>
> which expands to the integer constant 1.

Comment: i got this. but again the thing that comes in my mind is why will it return integer. the data type _Bool could have had its own native type which would take up only 1 Byte.

Answer (score -1):

Since the data types are predefined ,we cannot use the "bool" data type as it is not present in the documentation