# Why do major compilers use typedef for stdint.h but use #define for stdbool.h?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer, typedef

I just noticed that gcc and clang both appear to use typedefs for stdint.h but #define for stdbool.h.

example: [clang's stdint.h](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdint_8h_source.html)

```
 #ifdef __INT8_TYPE__
 #ifndef __int8_t_defined  /* glibc sys/types.h also defines int8_t*/
 typedef __INT8_TYPE__ int8_t;
 #endif /* __int8_t_defined */
 typedef __UINT8_TYPE__ uint8_t;
 # define __int_least8_t int8_t
 # define __uint_least8_t uint8_t
 #endif /* __INT8_TYPE__ */
```

[clang's stdbool.h](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdbool_8h_source.html)

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define bool _Bool
#define true 1
#define false 0
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)
/* Define _Bool, bool, false, true as a GNU extension. */
#define _Bool bool
#define bool  bool
#define false false
#define true  true
#endif
```

Why isn't it `typedef _Bool bool;` ?

(gcc [stdint.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1cb6c2eb3b8361d850be8e8270c597270a1a7967/gcc/ginclude/stdint-gcc.h) and [stdbool.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/1cb6c2eb3b8361d850be8e8270c597270a1a7967/gcc/ginclude/stdbool.h))

Comment: Not the same question, but you might find it interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666353/are-typedef-and-define-the-same-in-c

Comment: Boolean evaluations worked perfectly well before someone decided they did not, and glued `true` and `false` on top. The trouble is, *any value* not `0` in C is `true`. I never use the boolean type, I never use `true` or `false` because those properties are inherent in the C conditional testing.

Comment: @WeatherVane Apparently I have encountered some code which was translated more efficiently when using the `bool` type rather than integer. So I guess at least some compilers are seeing the difference.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10630231/1606345

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would have thought a good compiler would generate the same code. IMO this is a misguided sop for human (mis)understanding. C is not a high level language, and I never grasped why this was introduced.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Because it turns out regardless of how macho you think you are, other coders prefer to see `bool is_enabled` instead of `int is_enabled` because the former conveys more clearly the semantics of the acceptable values.

Comment: on many microprocessors, there are actual boolean bits.  Those bits are not 'int'  but rather real 'bool'.    On such microprocessors, a 'int' and a 'bool' are not the same thing.   Most CPUs, however, have not bit addressing capability so a 'bool' and a 'int' are the same

Comment: @user3629249 "Those bits are not 'int' but rather real 'bool'" -- we're talking about C here. The bool type never gets implemented as a bit here. The only way to manipulate single bits in C is to do the boolean math explicitly with bitwise and/or/xor/complement or to use bitfields.

Comment: @JasonS, compilers that are for C on microprocessors Have extensions for the real bitmapped area of their memory map.  The 8051 is such an example

Comment: ?? odd, I've never heard of such a compiler extension; I've worked with a variety of 8-bit and 16-bit embedded processors for the last 21 years.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`stdbool.h` defines `bool` as a macro because the C standard ([section 7.18](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.18)) says `bool` shall be defined as a macro, and `stdint.h` defines `intN_t` etc as typedefs because the C standard ([section 7.20](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20)) says `intN_t` etc shall be defined as typedefs.

Okay, why does the C standard say these things?  I cannot tell you for sure, but a clue is in section 7.18 paragraph 4:

> Notwithstanding the provisions of [7.1.3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3), a program may undefine and perhaps then redefine the macros bool, true, and false.

If `bool` were a typedef and `true` and `false` were, I don't know, `enum` constants, they couldn't have allowed you to do that, as there is no way to undo those kinds of declarations.

Okay, why does the C committee want to allow you to do that?  This is even more speculative, but probably for the same reason they added `stdbool.h` and `_Bool` instead of making `bool`, `true`, and `false` keywords as they are in C++: they wanted to preserve compatibility with old programs that defined `bool`, `true`, and `false` themselves, even if those programs use third-party headers that include `stdbool.h`...

No such backward compatibility concerns apply to the types defined by `stdint.h`; some systems provided (some) of them as extensions, but they were always typedefs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just part of the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

If you go to page 253, under ***"7.16 Boolean type and values "***, it clearly says:

> 1) The header `<stdbool.h>` defines four macros.
>
> 2) The macro
>
> `bool`
>
> expands to `_Bool`.

Comment: Then the question becomes *Why does the standard do it that way instead of `typedef _Bool bool`?*

Comment: Actually, the question is "Why do major compilers [...]" - and for bool, the answer is "because the standard says so". Correct so far, but only half of the answer ("why does `<stdint.h>` not is left open)...